# Facebook App Invite not working

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to add facebook App Invite like this:

```
let content:FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
        content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "https://fb.me/...")
        content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = URL(string: "http://...")

        let dialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
        dialog.content = content
        dialog.delegate = self
        dialog.fromViewController = self
        dialog.show()
```

Relevant Info.plist keys:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>...</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Blanket</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbapi20160328</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.my.app</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb...</string>
            <string>myappscheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

When I run the code, safari window is opened, and closed after showing loading spinner.

This error is returned:

`"Error: Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=2 \"(null)\" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid method_results., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=method_results})"`

Facebook app is installed on the device, and share dialog opens in facebook app.

When i try to debug, in `[FBSDKApplicationDelegate _handleBridgeAPIResponseURL:sourceApplication:]`  response URL is `fb...://bridge/appinvites?version=web&bridge_args=%7B%22app_name%22%3A%22...%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%...%22%7D&error=%7B%22error%22%3A%22server_error%22%2C%22error_description%22%3A%22Error%20retrieving%20application%20configuration.%22%7D`

relevant error:

```
{"error":"server_error","error_description":"Error retrieving application configuration."}
```

I'm not sure what that error means, is facebook application config wrong, or iOS application.

The same invite works on Android, iOS app is published, and has valid iTunes URL configured.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34468728/5461400

Answer (score 2):

I was able to invite friends based on the above code so please check the facebook app id and see whether it is entered correctly. And see whether you have provided the correct url identifier and url scheme in the p list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and see if it works in wifi. It seems there is a bug in facebook App Invite which doesn't work in mobile data but works when using wifi (getting the same error as above.)

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/798217780334522/

If it is working in wifi and not working in mobile data pls report thru that link above to resolve it.

Comment: The bugs been confirmed at facebook team is trying to fix it now. Can be seen from the link.